# PFUser and PFFile for user picture

Tags: parse-platform, ios9

first of all:

- parse: 1.8.5, xcode 7, iOS 9

I have this simple PFUser structure:

```
_User: {...,picture:PFFile, picture_thumb:PFFile,...}
```

when I save picture for user I make this:

on

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]){   
...
     let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageResized!, 0.7)
     let picture = PFFile(name: "picture.jpg", data: imageData!)

     self.viewUploadPicture.hidden = false
     self.progressUploadPicture.progress = 0.0

     PFUser.currentUser()?.setObject(picture, forKey: "picture")
     picture.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success:Bool, error:NSError?) -> Void in
         self.progressUploadPicture.progress = 0.0
         self.viewUploadPicture.hidden = true

         if error != nil {
            print("upload image error: \(error?.userInfo)")
            return
         }
         print("upload image OK")
         self.imgUser.image = imageResized
         self.imageUpdated = true
         PFUser.currentUser()?.saveInBackground()
     }, progressBlock: { (perc:Int32) -> Void in
         print("uploading image \(Float(perc)/100)%")
         self.viewUploadPicture.hidden = false
         self.progressUploadPicture.progress = Float(perc)/100
         self.lblUploadPicturePerc.text = "\(Float(perc))%"
      })

}
```

where **imageResized** is the image... well,  self explicative ;), and other controls used too, used for UX

ok, the issue I have is that if I delete and restart the app on my test device after the login, when I run the AccountDetail view controller I would to display the user I stored of course but this is what I have

```
typealias UserFoundHandler = (PFUser) -> Void

func checkParseUser(userHandler:UserFoundHandler)  {

   guard  let user:PFUser = PFUser.currentUser() else {
      return
   }
   user.fetchInBackgroundWithBlock({ (remoteUser:PFObject?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
      guard let user:PFUser = PFUser.currentUser() else {
         self.presentParseLoginSignUp()
         return
      }
      userHandler(user)            
   })
}
```

and calling the function below the code within the first ***if*** is not executed because the type of picture is a NSData instead of a PFFile like the pticure_thumb field saved correctly following the parse tutorial about Image module .

the trouble is why! do I miss something?

```
func fromUserToComponents(user:PFUser){
    print("fromUserToComponents \(user)")

   if let imageFile: PFFile = user.objectForKey("picture") as? PFFile {
        ... code to set fill an UIImageView
    }
}
```

the print result is:

```
fromUserToComponents <PFUser: 0x165c77b0, objectId: D8VGNQOJzu, localId: (null)> {
    nickname = "Attilio Patania";
    picture = <ffd8ffe0 00104a46 49460001 01000048 00480000 ffe1004c 45786966 00004d4d 002a0000 00080002 01120003
    ....
    00d7b7fe cd5f38d3 2933ffd9>;
    "picture_thumb" = "<PFFile: 0x165ab480>";
}
```